# NSIS WriteIniStr

Tags: nsis

I am trying to overwrite an existing value in my Application .config file using NSIS.

I want to change 'endpoint address="http://DefaultWebService.asmx"'

to 'endpoint address="http://MyWebService.asmx"'

My Config file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://DefaultWebService.asmx"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceSoap12"
    contract="WebServiceProxies.MyServiceSoap" name="MyServiceSoap12" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In my NSIS I'm using :

```
WriteIniStr "$MyApp.exe.config" "system.serviceModel" "endpoint address" "endpoint address="http://MyWebService.asmx"
```

but this just adds

```
[system.serviceModel]
endpoint address=http://MyWebService.asmx
```

to the bottom of the .config file.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using WriteIniStr which updates .ini files and application.config is an XML file. You need to use something like [this](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/XML_plug-in) plug-in instead.